# Location of java packages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package

For importing java packages we usually use,

import java.util.*;

For looking the location of this package, instead of using windows explorer, how can I get the location of imported java packages from eclipse?

Or more precisely, what is the command in eclispe for locating those imported java packages?

Comment: Wouldn't these be a part of your JDK install ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Package Explorer you can see the location (in my case it is c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib):

[image]

If you don't know that it is in the rt.jar, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on one class from java.util, for instance java.util.List and with the Link to Editor activated you'll see it (or look inside the rt.jar by clicking on the small triangle next to rt.jar).

Comment: Thank you, I have got the idea now ... :) .. though I was expecting something like, right clicking on the "import java.util.*;", then navigate to location of that package.

Answer (score 0):

Java packages do not have a fixed location. In your system, they are inside some `jar` file inside your JDK or JRE installation. In another system they could be in a completely different location - but your program will work just as well.

However, if you want to navigate through the packages, you can do so using *Project Explorer*, *Package Explorer* or *Open Type* dialog box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>).